# mySQL PHP query to arrange results in groups

Tags: php, mysql

My problem is with a customer service database i am currently writing. I don't have great knowledge of sql queries and i'm really having a hard time getting the query right.

i have two tables:

```
**Customers:**
idcustomer
company_name
tel_number
address
postcode

**customer_machines**
id_customer_machine
id_customer
date_last_service
date_service_due
```

I want to select results that show which machines are due for a service between a given set of dates (for example machines due in month 9).

```
SELECT customer_machines.* from customer_machines WHERE (customer_machines.date_next_service BETWEEN '2013-09-01' AND '2013-10-01') ORDER BY date_next_service ASC;
```

this is fine however some customer's have more than one machine e.g.

```
+---------------------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| id_customer_machine | id_customer | date_last_service | date_next_service |
+---------------------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|                   1 |           1 | 2012-09-02        | 2013-09-02        |
|                   2 |           2 | 2012-09-14        | 2013-09-14        |
|                   3 |           3 | 2012-09-30        | 2013-09-30        |
|                   5 |           3 | 2012-09-30        | 2013-09-30        |
+---------------------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

I need to group machines by which customer owns them, join the customer's details and output to a table in the browser something like:

```
Customer 1     address of customer 1     tel of customer 1     postcode of customer 1
machine-id-1                                 date-last-service      date-next-service
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
customer 2     address of customer 2     tel of customer 2     postcode of customer 2
machine-id-2                                 date-last-service     date-next-service
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
customer 3     address of customer 3     tel of customer 3     postcode of customer 3
machine-id-3                                date-last-service     date-next-service
machine-id-5                                date-last-service     date-next-service
```

Can i arrange the results together like this with a single query? so far i have only tried nesting queries in php with no success.

If you could point me in the right direction that would be great

thanks

Comment: Did you try to join the intermediate result with customers table?

Comment: Just order by customer,service-date and handle the display logic in the presentation layer/application level code (e.g. a simple php loop)

Comment: why don't you look for a free customer service application and look how it's done? you seem very novice, facing a project out of your skill (heck, it's even out of my skills, and i'm not a novice)

Answer (score 0):

SQL does not have a feature to build nested results, only plain tables.
In some simple cases, you can use `GROUP_CONCAT` to concatenate values. For example:

```
SELECT 
  id_customer, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(id_customer_machine SEPARATOR ', ') as id_customer_machines
FROM customer_machines;
```

would output you:

```
+-------------+----------------------+
| id_customer | id_customer_machines |
+------------------------------------+
|           1 |                    1 |
|           2 |                    2 |
|           3 |                 3, 5 | 
+-------------+----------------------+
```

But since you need to group more than one column, this would not help you. 
In your case you have two options:

1. Fetch all customer ids, then iterate over them, fetching customer machines for every id_customer. Simpler, but not efficient (numCustomers + 1 queries).
2. Fetch plain data from database and make structured array from it by means of PHP. Efficient, but more coding.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to select relevant data from both tables e.g :

`SELECT c.*, cm.id_customer_machine, cm.date_last_service, cm.date_service_due from Customers c, customer_machines cm WHERE c.idcustomer = cm.customer_id AND (customer_machines.date_next_service BETWEEN '2013-09-01' AND '2013-10-01') ORDER BY date_next_service ASC;`

However, that may not be ideal because you will end up with duplicated customer data too for each machine found.

As an alternative you could loop through each customer and select all the results from the second table based on the users id and build it into an array or object e.g :

`$customerArr = array();`

`$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","schema");`

`$customerResult = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Customers");`

`while($customerRow = mysqli_fetch_array($customerResult)){`

`$customerArr[$customerRow['idcustomer']];`

`$macineResult = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM customer_machines WHERE customer_id = 'customerRow['idcustomer']'");`

`while($machineRow = mysqli_fetch_array($machineResult)){`

`$customerArr[$customerRow['idcustomer']][$machineRow['id_customer_machine']]['date_last_service'] = $machineRow['date_last_service'];`

`$customerArr[$customerRow['idcustomer']][$machineRow['id_customer_machine']]['date_next_service'] = $machineRow['date_next_service'];`

`}`

`}`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a single query, but the loop in your PHP code will get a bit more complicated than using separate queries

```
SELECT * from customer_machines
INNER JOIN customers USING(customer_id)
WHERE (customer_machines.date_next_service BETWEEN '2013-09-01' AND '2013-10-01')
ORDER BY date_next_service ASC;
```

This should give you something like:

```
customer_id | machine_id | company_name | etc | other column | more data | ...
    1       |     1      | xxxx
    2       |     2      | xxxx
    3       |     3      | xxxx
    3       |     5      | xxxx
```

your loop:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $data[ $row[customer_id][] = $row;
}
```

this will give you an array similar to:

```
array(
    [1] => array(
         [0] => array(
              [company_name] => name,
              the remaining customer and machine data
         )
    ),
    [2] => array(
         [0] => array(
              [company_name] => name,
              the remaining customer and machine data
         )
    ),
    [3] => array(
         [0] => array(
              [company_name] => name,
              the remaining customer and machine data
         ),
         [1] => array(
              [company_name] => name,
              the remaining customer and machine data
         )
    )
```

Just iterate over that array to print the data; You will need 2 loops to do this.

An other solution is to first select all customers, loop over it and foreach customer select the machine info you want to display. You will get a lot of queries by doing this.